# Is 'The Night The Sky Cried Tears Of Fire' by J.D. Cronise an actual novel?

Tags: music

So there's this music album 'Warp Riders' by a band called 'The Sword', which follows the storyline written by the vocalist/guitarist J.D. Cronise. Wikipedia makes it sound like an actual book and not just a rough skectch:

> The story of Warp Riders, entitled "The Night The Sky Cried Tears Of Fire" (written by Cronise), follows Ereth as he discovers ... - from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp_Riders

So my question is, is there any information on the state in which this back-story exists (notes, concept, novel)?

Note: I know they plan on releasing a comic to go along with Warp Riders. That's not what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [synopsis](http://kingofthenerds.wordpress.com/tag/the-sword/) for the story that was originally posted on the [band's website](http://swordofdoom.com/?page_id=2);

[image: Warp Riders]

> "Warp Riders tells the tale of Ereth, an archer banished from his tribe
>   on the planet Acheron. A hardscrabble planet that has undergone a
>   tidal lock, which has caused one side to be scorched by three suns,
>   and the other enshrouded in perpetual darkness, it is the background
>   for a tale of strife and fantasy, the battle between pure good and
>   pure evil. ….The story of Warp Riders, entitled “The Night The Sky
>   Cried Tears Of Fire” (written by Cronise), follows Ereth as he
>   discovers a mysterious orb and meets the Chronomancer, a being beyond
>   time and space who enlists him in a quest to restore the planet’s
>   balance. Along the way he encounters strange warriors, mysterious
>   witches, ancient androids, and a crew of space pirates with a vessel
>   that will alter the course of history…  a vessel known as, The Sword"

With the exception of song lyrics for his various albums, there don't seem to be any published or [copyrighted](http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=cronise&Search_Code=NALL&PID=R9DUR2rSv16zqfE-TyV3XpL7KWu6&SEQ=20140114180655&CNT=25&HIST=1) works of fiction written by [John "J. D." Cronise](http://www.metal-archives.com/artists/J._D._Cronise/23763), the lead songwriter of The Sword